# Is there a debug version of the Chrome Flash Player

Tags: flash, google-chrome

Does Google publish a debug version of their Pepper flash player, akin to Adobe's debug version of the standard player (http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html)?

I would like to debug my Flex app in Chrome without disabling Pepper.

Answer (score 2):

The debug version of the PPAPI Flash Player for Chrome and Opera has been released.  They are available in the Flash Player Downloads page:

https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Direct links:

http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/17/flashplayer_17_ppapi_debug.exe

http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/17/flashplayer_17_ppapi_debug.dmg

Answer (score 0):

There is no debug version of the PPAPI (Pepper) Flash Player.  See Chris Campbell's comment here:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/6183381 (posted Mar 4, 2014)

> We currently do not have a debug player available for PPAPI at this time.  This is something we're working on and hope to have addressed later this year.

Also refer to this issue where there is more likely to be traction on getting the debug version released: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=153130

Answer (score 0):

As of a few weeks ago, the debug (beta) version of PPAPI Flash is now available from Adobe Labs:
http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer.html

Answer (score 0):

Since Chrome 54 didn't even download Flash at install, you need to manually copy the PepperFlash.plugin into Chromes components after you installed the Debug version of the PPAPI player from Adobe https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html

Example:

```
cp -R /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/PepperFlashPlayer/PepperFlashPlayer.plugin ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/PepperFlash/23.0.0.207/
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use Monster Debugger: http://demonsterdebugger.com/home

Comment: Monster Debugger, even if it is a good app, does not replace the native debug. Since Pepper Flash does not behave exactly the same way that original player, it would be very interresting to be able to debug with.